# The file failed to upload. Error when I try to upload images on hosting. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upload an image then there was an error "The file failed to upload." Then I tried to upload an image under 1MB in size but the error still occurred. When I try to upload on localhost it works but when on Hosting it fails. I don't know what else I need to fix. I just want that before going to the voting page the user has to upload an image below 2MB on the upload page then redirect to the voting page and vote. Sorry for my bad English. I hope you understand.

[image]

**upload.blade.php**

```
@extends('voting.navlogout')
@section('judul','Pemilihan Presiden BEM UMS')
@section('konten')
    <div class="mycontainer" style="overflow-x:hidden">
    <div class="row">
 
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card mx-auto mb-5 cardku">
             
                 <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                  <div class="row">
                    <h1>Sebelum Voting Silahkan Upload KTM</h1>
                      <div class="col">
                        @if(count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            {{ $error }} <br/>
                          @endforeach
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        <form action="/upload/proses" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                          <b>PASTIKAN FOTO KTM JELAS</b>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <div align="left">
                          Nama Lengkap
                          <input type="text" name="nama">
                          <br>
                          Upload KTM <b>(ukuran max: 3MB)</b><br/>
                          <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary">
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**VotingController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Kandidat;
use App\Voting;
use App\Voters;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class VotingController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(Request $data)
    {
        $voter = DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$data->session()->get('token'))->get();
        foreach($voter as $v) {
            $ktm = $v->image;
        }
        if($data->session()->get('token')){
            //Jika Ada Session     
            if(empty($ktm)){
                return redirect('upload');
            }else{
                $kandidat = Kandidat::all();
                return view('voting.index',[
                    'kandidat' => $kandidat, 'voter' => $voter
                ]);
            }    
                
        }else{
            // jika tidak ada session
            return redirect('/votinglogin');
        }
 
    }

    public function simpansuara($idkandidat,Request $data)
    {
        $jumlah = DB::table('kandidat')->where('id',$idkandidat)->get();

        foreach ($jumlah as $key) {
             $jumlahsuara = $key->jumlahsuara;
        }
        DB::table('kandidat')->where('id',$idkandidat)->update([
            'jumlahsuara' => $jumlahsuara+1
        ]);
        DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$data->session()->get('token'))->update([
            'status'  => 1,
            'memilih' => $idkandidat
        ]);
        return redirect ('/logoutvoting');
    }
    public function apisimpansuara(Request $data)
    {
        $idkandidat = $data->idkandidat;
        $token      = $data->token;
        $jumlah = DB::table('kandidat')->where('id',$idkandidat)->get();
        $voter = DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$token)->get();
        foreach($voter as $v) {
            $statusvoter = $v->status;
        }
        if($statusvoter == 2){
        foreach ($jumlah as $key) {
             $jumlahsuara = $key->jumlahsuara;
        }
        DB::table('kandidat')->where('id',$idkandidat)->update([
            'jumlahsuara' => $jumlahsuara+1
        ]);
        DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$token)->update([
            'status'  => 1,
            'memilih' => $idkandidat
        ]);
        $success = '1';
        $msg = 'Berhasil';
        }else{
            $success = '0';
            $msg = 'Gagal';
        }
        return response()->json([
                    'success' => $success,
                    'message' => $msg
                ]);
    }
    
    public function logoutvoting(Request $data){
        $data->session()->forget('token');
        $voter = DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$data->session()->get('token'))->get();
        return view ('voting.logout',['voter' => $voter]);
    }
    
    public function daftartoken()
    {
        $token = DB::table('pemilih')->where('status','2')->get();
        foreach($token as $tkn) {
            echo $tkn->username;
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<br>';
        } 
    }
    
    public function upload(Request $request){
        $gambar = Voters::get();
        $voter = DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$request->session()->get('token'))->get();
        if($request->session()->get('token')){
            return view('voting.upload',['pemilih' => $gambar,'voter' => $voter]);
        }else{
            return redirect('votinglogin');
        }
    }

    public function proses_upload(Request $request){
        $voter = DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$request->session()->get('token'))->get();
        foreach($voter as $v) {
            $nim = $v->username;
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'nama' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3072'
        ]);
 
        // menyimpan data file yang diupload ke variabel $file
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama = $request->nama;
 
        $nama_file = $nim.'_'.$nama.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
 
        // isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'mahasiswa';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
 
        DB::table('pemilih')->where('username',$request->session()->get('token'))->update([
            'image' => $nama_file
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('voting');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index');
Route::get('/votinglogin','UserController@votinglogin')->name('votinglogin');
Route::post('/votinglogin','VoterController@tambah')->name('daftar');
// Route Voting
Route::get('/voting','VotingController@index')->name('voting');
Route::post('/cektoken','UserController@cektoken')->name('cektoken');
Route::get('/simpansuara/{id}','VotingController@simpansuara')->name('simpansuara');
Route::get('/logoutvoting','VotingController@logoutvoting')->name('logoutvoting');

// Route KTM
Route::get('/upload', 'VotingController@upload');
Route::post('/upload/proses', 'VotingController@proses_upload');
```

Comment: Please post error log either from laravel.log file or from network tab in browser inspect

Comment: [laravel.log](https://pastebin.com/Y3R6zw1n) [network tab in browser inspect](https://imgur.com/dA2VzCp)